# Знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Верно ли стоят знаки препинания: «запрос о правовой помощи, или, иначе говоря, о производстве процессуальных действий, - это документ...»?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, ваша пунктуация возможна. Если вы рассматриваете конструкцию "или... действий" как уточняющую к "запрос о помощи". Попробую сейчас найти что-нибудь в рекомендациях.

Что действительно вызывает сомнения, так это стык запятой и тире. Подобное тут (и не только тут) неоднократно обсуждалось, к единому мнению не пришли.

Ну вот есть в нацкорпусе пример - точь-в-точь ваш. Насколько его можно принять на эталон, судить не бурусь.

*Владимир Шпикалов. В здравоохранении эксперименты недопустимы (2003) // «Восточно-Сибирская правда» (Иркутск), 2003.06.21   [омонимия не снята] Все примеры (1) Врач общей практики, или, другими словами, семейный врач, ― это специалист с высшим медицинским образованием, имеющий юридическое право оказывать первичную многопрофильную медико-социальную помощь независимо от возраста и пола пациентов. [Владимир Шпикалов. В здравоохранении эксперименты недопустимы (2003) // «Восточно-Сибирская правда» (Иркутск), 2003.06.21] [омонимия не снята]*

***Тире с запятой обсуждаем [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9)***

Answer (score 1):

Вводное выражение *иначе говоря* здесь неспроста. Оно дает понять, что перед нами не однородные члены предложения (*помощи* и *производстве*). Союз *или* здесь в значении "то есть", а *или... о производстве процессуальных действий* -- выражение, уточняющее смысл "правовой помощи", соответственно должно быть обособлено запятыми с обеих сторон.

Приведу [параграф из Грамоты.ру](http://gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_33):

VIII. Запятые при словах и группах слов, ограничивающих или уточняющих другие слова в предложении.

§ 154. Запятыми выделяются слова и группы слов, ограничивающие или уточняющие смысл предыдущих или следующих за ними слов и присоединяемые к ним непосредственно или посредством слов: в том числе, включая, исключая, за исключением, кроме, именно, по имени  (по фамилии и т. п.), то есть, ***или  (в значении «то есть»)***, иначе, иначе говоря, например, как например, скажем, как-то, особенно, даже, и притом, и (в значении «и притом») и т. п...

Итого:
*Запрос о правовой помощи, или [то есть], иначе говоря, о производстве процессуальных действий, - это документ...*

Ответ на комментарий [[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus):

Считаю, что тире и запятая при стыке обязательно должны сохраняться, иначе, к примеру в сложных, громоздких, предложениях, иногда днем с огнем не сыщешь, где заканчивается уточнение или какой-либо иной оборот. Не вижу смысла в таком поглощении, так как с ним все только усложниться (а именно читаемость). Лучше поставить запятую вместе с тире, чем искать по всему предложению, где оборот заканчивается. Притом внутри самой вставленной конструкции может присутствовать тире. Я за простоту и очевидность языковых правил.

По поводу однозначности уточнения у меня также сомнений не возникает. Вроде бы все (или почти все) с этим согласны.

Comment: @__inna__, это все так, но тут больших сомнений и нет. Вопрос в том, одназначна ли трактовка как уточняющего. 
 
Ну и конечно, стык тире и запятой. Должно ли терие "поглощать" запятую или оба знака должны сохраняться.

Comment: Тире запятую не поглощает. Но вопрос в интерпретации того, почему стоят запятые. ИМХО.

Comment: Вы уверены? А зачем тогда Розенталь прописал несолько конкретных случае, когда это действительно не происходит?

Comment: Возможно имелось в виду, что конструкция ", -" имеет право на существование, а "- ," - нет? Дайте конкретные примеры (пункты у Розенталя) - мне сейчас некогда искать.

Comment: Плюсанул. Считаю ответ на комментарий @behemothus вполне разумным.

Comment: @behemothus, по-моему, у Розенталя идет речь о том, что запятая поглощает тире, а не тире запятую. То есть когда при парных тире второе из них опускается. А у нас здесь нет парных тире.

Comment: Интересно о сочетании и поглощении знаков препинания здесь http://russkiyjazik.ru/291/ 
Про тире и запятую:
Тире «поглощает» только первую из двух запятых, а со второй прекрасно уживается: «Говорили они долго — [®судя по спидометру,] в течение нескольких лет, — а потом вдруг сразу исчезли, и стало пусто.
«Проглотить» одно из двух тире под силу только точке с запятой и двоеточию. С запятой два тире совместимы: «Но чёрта с два от них оторвёшься: одни, с микрофоном, — справа; другой, с фотоаппарате) и, — еяева».
Знак парное тире «съедает» первую из двух запятых, но спокойно совмещается со второй

Comment: Примеры взяты из статьи по ссылке, а автор статьи цитирует Стругацких. Может, там не все по смыслу понятно, но нас же пунктуация интересует. Просмотрите, пожалуйста, первоисточник (http://russkiyjazik.ru/291/).

Comment: Вы абсолютно не включая мозг скопировали. В оригинале выглядело так:

> Но черта с два от них оторвешься: один, с микрофоном, — справа, другой, с фотоаппаратом, — слева.

По-моему, совершенно по-другому звучит и не вызывает диссонанса.

Comment: Да, вы правы. Не сразу вчиталась, пардон.

Comment: тире с запятой обьсуждаем здесь:

http://russ.hashcode.ru/questions/7676/%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9

Answer (score 0):

Не согласен с "gecube" по следующим причинам:
1. В данном предложении союз "или" используется не в разделительном, а в пояснительном значении, равном "то есть". В качестве примера по многим учебникам в свое время "гуляло" предложение: "В зоопарке жил бегемот,или гиппопотам". В таком случае перед союзом "или" ставится запятая.
2. Что касается запятой перед тире, то на этот счет можно посмотреть у Розенталя раздел "Обособление уточняющих, присоединительных, пояснительных членов предложения". Запятой перед тире мы закрываем обособленный пояснительный член предложения, а затем ставим тире перед "это".
 Так что знаки препинания  стоят верно.

Answer (score 0):

1. В бессоюзном сложном предложении может ставиться запятая и тире как единый знак, особенно при значении присоединения во второй части предложения (знак этот в настоящее время утрачивает свою активность):
   Смотреть наружу не было смысла, — тьма ночи налетала всё более густыми волнами (Пауст.);
2. Запятую и тире как единый знак препинания не следует смешивать с сочетанием этих знаков, когда тире разграничивает части бессоюзного сложного предложения, а запятая отделяет впереди стоящую обособленную конструкцию или придаточную часть предложения: 
   Не прошло и трех часов с восхода солнца, а уж казалось, что близок полдень, — так жарко, светло было всюду и так многолюдно возле лавок в конце улицы  (Бун.);

В заданном вопросе -- второй случай: запятая и тире стоят на разных основаниях, запятая закрывает уточняющее приложение, а тире стоит между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: то есть, не уточняющее приложение, а, скорее, пояснительный член.

Comment: Да, пояснительный член предложения. Именно об этом я писал в своем ответе 14 агуста(см.выше)