# О стыке тире и запятой

Tags: пунктуация

Как пунктуационно оформляется "стык" тире и запятой?

Обсуждение этой проблемы явно вышло за рамки комментария.
[тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7602/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

...
Ну и конечно, стык тире и запятой. Должно ли тире "поглощать" запятую или оба знака должны сохраняться.
(5 часов назад) behemothus
...
Тире запятую не поглощает. Но вопрос в интерпретации того, почему стоят запятые. ИМХО.
(5 часов назад) gecube
...
А насчет поглощения... Вы уверены? А зачем тогда Розенталь прописал несколько конкретных случае, когда это действительно не происходит?
(5 часов назад) behemothus
...

Возможно имелось в виду, что конструкция ", -" имеет право на существование, а "- ," - нет? Дайте конкретные примеры (пункты у Розенталя) - мне сейчас некогда искать.
(5 часов назад) gecube Плюсанул. Считаю ответ на комментарий @behemothus вполне разумным.
(5 часов назад) gecube @behemothus, по-моему, у Розенталя идет речь о том, что запятая поглощает тире, а не тире запятую. То есть когда при парных тире второе из них опускается. А у нас здесь нет парных тире.
(1 час назад) **inna**

Интересно о сочетании и поглощении знаков препинания здесь http://russkiyjazik.ru/291/ Про тире и запятую: Тире «поглощает» только первую из двух запятых, а со второй прекрасно уживается: «Говорили они долго — [®судя по спидометру,] в течение нескольких лет, — а потом вдруг сразу исчезли, и стало пусто. «Проглотить» одно из двух тире под силу только точке с запятой и двоеточию. С запятой два тире совместимы: «Но чёрта с два от них оторвёшься: один, с микрофоном, — справа; другой, с фотоаппаратом, — слева». Знак парное тире «съедает» первую из двух запятых, но спокойно совмещается со второй.
(1 час назад) **inna**

Примеры взяты из статьи по ссылке, а автор статьи цитирует Стругацких. Может, там не все по смыслу понятно, но нас же пунктуация интересует. Просмотрите, пожалуйста, первоисточник (http://russkiyjazik.ru/291/).
...
(я опустил личные тёрки)

=====

Продолжаем здесь.

По поводу того, что там чего поглощает.

Я, говоря о формулировке Розенталя, имел в виду §113 "Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении и в периоде" справочника по литературной правке:

*Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении ставятся в качестве единого знака:
1) перед главным предложением, которому предшествует ряд однородных придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного целого на две части...

2) перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения...

3) в художественной речи в периоде ... между его частями...

Внутри частей периода, если они значительно распространены, в художественной речи ставится точка с запятой. Реже между частями (членами) периода ставятся запятые...*

Тут действительно формулировки оставляют вопросы, но я никогда не слышал, чтобы кто-то понимал эти правила как изъятия из правила "запятая поглощаяет тире" (как настаивает @*inna*), а не наоборот.

=====

> > > Просмотрите, пожалуйста, первоисточник (http://russkiyjazik.ru/291).

Первоисточник интересный. Не очень понятно, правда, насколько авторитетный. Но дело даже не в этом. Там (как и везде, где по этому поводу пишут) представлены отдельные соображения по поводу стыка парных тире и запятых (тоже обычно парных), но нет четкой позиции по поводу стыка парной запятой и непарного тире.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поднял старый вопрос. *Были причины о нем вспомнить, к самому вопросу отношения не имеющие.*

При всей благодарности к участникам, ***исчерпывающего*** правила так никто и не дал. Судя по всему, его никто и не сформулировал. Все сказанное - только частные случаи.
Может, я по-прежненму чего-то не понимаю.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, в первую очередь надо разграничить тире с запятой в сложном предложении и в простом, но с усложнениями (с ОЧП, приложениями и различными обособленными оборотами). Про "поглощение" запятой тире я взяла из параграфа 19 "Обособленные приложения" ("Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация" Розенталя). В конце этого параграфа есть примечание, когда второе тире опускается. Первый случай: если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая:
*Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор - весы, то понял бы источник ошибки.*
*Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, - Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (газ.)*

Есть еще три случая...

Дополняю.
Мне не очень нравится теория про запятую с тире как единый знак. Если разобраться, каждый из них играет свою роль, каждый по-своему важен. Какой смысл избавляться от одного из них? Запятая (парная) не дает нам забыть о границах предложений, уточнений, оборотов, а вот тире (по словам Розенталя) имеет особый статус среди других знаков препинания. "Он [знак тире] выполняет как грамматические (чисто синтаксические), так и эмоционально-экспрессивные функции..." (Иванова В. Ф.) Кроме того, Розенталь делает вывод об агрессивности тире (из параграфа 72 "Вариативные знаки препинания", "Пунктуация"). Действительно, тире все чаще вытесняет, например, двоеточие (то есть заменяет). А вот насчет поглощения запятой - разве что в таком случае:

*Говорили они долго — [®судя по спидометру,] в течение нескольких лет, — а потом вдруг сразу исчезли, и стало пусто*

Первая запятая действительно поглощена тире. Но при этом роль второй парной тире нельзя недооценивать.

*Делал ли что-нибудь для этого Штольц, что делал и как делал, - мы этого не знаем.* (Пример из параграфа 113)

Здесь, на мой взгляд, нужна запятая, так как она помогает понять, сколько в сложном предложении простых (то есть три). Оно вроде и так понятно, но эта запятая своего рода подстраховка, чтобы лишний раз не запутаться. А без нее грани последних двух предложений как бы стираются. Тире же объединяет каждое из первых двух предложений с третьим. В итоге: запятая разделяет, тире объединяет в данном примере... Ну не укладывается в голове, как ее может не быть...

Comment: Это "Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация"?

Да, согласен, там есть один случай, который можно интерпретировать как "поглощение" запятой "половинки" парного тире. Но это, вроде, не наш случай... У нас исходно разговор шёл о непарном тире.

Comment: Да, я уже уточнила)

Comment: ... Разговор шел о непарном тире и о простом предложении... То есть существует мнение, отличное от мнения Розенталя, что вместо запятой и тире как единого знака лучше ставить одно тире?

Comment: Существует мнение, что вы сослались на Розенталя не по делу.    
Вопросы.  
1. Что такое единый знак и чем он отличается от "неединого" стыка тире и запятой? Другими словами, всякую ли последовательность "запятая+тире" надо трактовать как единый знак?   
2. Где конкретно Розенталь говорит о случае одиночного тире при встрече его с парной запятой? В простом предложении, разумеется. 
3. О каком случае говорите вы, ссылаясь на его мнение?

Comment: I. Я в курсе насчет единого знака и неединого. Далеко не каждую последовательность тире и запятой надо понимать как единый знак. Об этом - в параграфе 113 справочника по лит. правке Розенталя, на который Вы сослались, говоря о проблеме сочетания запятой и тире. Взяла оттуда пример (про Штольца) и попыталась разобраться. Но там речь идет уже о сложном (СП) предложении, а не о простом. Я не могу понять суть проблемы, ищу ее и не нахожу. Не могли бы Вы раскрыть ее? Какие аргументы есть в пользу поглощения одного знака другим? В каких случаях, в каких предложениях?..

Comment: II. Именно в этом же параграфе у Розенталя - про одиночное тире при встрече с парными запятыми (которые обрамляют части СПП, как я понимаю). Я говорю о том случае, на который Вы и указали, ни о каком другом ("Запятая и тире в СПП и периоде"). Также пару слов я уделила только тире и его роли в синтаксисе и в речи вообще, с тем чтобы подчеркнуть, что у тире - своя роль, у запятой своя - даже в том случае, когда их сочетание считают единым знаком.

Comment: >>>Я в курсе насчет единого знака и неединого.   
Это я был не в курсе относительно вашей позиции. Вы согласны с определением @Ларф?

Answer (score 1):

На вопрос из комментария:

**Единый знак** - два знака ставятся **на одном основании**, но при наличии дополнительных условий.  Например, **между частями сложного предложения**,  если ряд однородных придаточных стоит перед главной частью, которая выполняет обобщающую функцию, при этом предложение распадается на две части, и перед главной частью делается длительная пауза: *Сколько лет король так жил с такой женой, что поддерживало его в трудные минуты, почему он не сделался злым и жестоким, - этого я не могу объяснить.*

**Сочетание знаков** – два знака ставятся **каждый на своем основании**.  Например, запятая **закрывает   оборот**,  тире стоит  **между частями сложного предложения**.

Comment: Спасибо.  
Хорошо, допустим. Надобы услышаь, что __inna__ так же понимает эту вещь конкретно у Розенталя. Я ведь этот вопрос задавал конкретному собеседнику, с которым у меня наметилось терминологическое недопонимание.  
  
Вообще я встречал такую трактовку, хотя не могу сказать, что она однозначна. Но беда-то в том, что при этом не исключается возможность постановки запятой и тире именно как сочетания (в вашей терминологии). И по поводу основного вопроса ничего не проясняет.

Comment: На 100 % не могу согласиться с этим утверждением. При всем уважении к Розенталю и к @Ларf. Я бы сказала, что это условно единый знак, по сравнению с сочетанием знаков, где постановка каждого из них более очевидна.

Comment: Не могу почему-то добавить комментарий под своим ответом, поэтому здесь отвечу @behemothus.
"Вместе с тем, "сочетания" знаков русския пунктуация последовательно избегает."
Ну почему же, у Розенталя в "Пунктуации" есть целый 18-й раздел "Сочетания знаков препинания", и первый параграф из него - 64-й "Запятая и тире".

Comment: У вас там четыре комментария к одному ответу. Ограничения движка или настроек форума.

Да, у Розенталя есть параграф, но это скорее исключения, в целом никак не отражает картины "поглощения". Не будь этой ситуации и не понадобилось писать параграфы. 

Короче, мы "зациклились". Вы возражаете *мне*, а не проблеме.
Сколько помню, этим всегда и кончается попытка разобраться в этом "сочетании".   )))

Comment: Я повторю, может другими словами. Мне хотелось бы видеть четко прописанное правило (желательно с сылками), когда запятая перед или после тире исчезает (нормативно или факультативно, надеюсь вы не будете отрицать, что такие случаи есть), когда она, переносится перед тире (если нужно бы поставить после, что невозможно) и когда она стоит на своём месте перед тире и никаким образом не подлежит опущению. Вот тогда я скажу, что вопрос исчерпан и закрыт.

Comment: Что же, остается по крупицам собирать отдельные "пунктики", а там гляди - и лет через надцать появится новая сводка правил о "поглощении" ("заглатывании" или "поедании") одних знаков препинания другими :)))