# Когда знаки препинания варьируются?

Tags: пунктуация

Я слышал, что тире может варьироваться с запятой, скобками, кавычками.  Расскажите о случаях с БСП, пожалуйста!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**В БСП в одном и том же предложении можно поставить запятую, тире, двоеточие.** Это объясняется тем, что неоднородные (взаимообусловленные)  отношения можно обозначить с помощью **присоединительной запятой** (обычно при наличии элементов, помогающих определить эту неоднородность), с  помощью **присоединительного или разделительного тире** (разные значения и  интонация!) или **пояснительного двоеточия** (с точным указанием значения следствие - причина).

**Приложение**

В качестве примера можно привести известное и очень спорное предложение **"Работа не волк, в лес не убежит"** (встречаются различные варианты его оформления).

1) С одной стороны,  **для постановки запятой   есть формальные признаки в виде структурных элементов:** частица НЕ, противопоставление. Ясно, что **предложение неоднородное и там присутствует взаимообусловленность,**  поэтому можно обойтись без таких сильных знаков, как двоеточие или тире.

2)  С другой стороны, двоеточие и тире здесь трудно выбрать по смыслу, так как   в  пословице  возможны **два смысловых оттенка и два вывода**.

Работа не убежит, как волк в лес, поэтому:
(1) не торопись с выполнением работы, она никуда не денется; 
(2) работу лучше  скорее выполнить, так как никто ее за тебя не сделает.

3) **Эти разные смысловые оттенки  в самом предложении не обозначены,** да и сравнение с волком для понимания смысла  является образным, попутным.  А основной смысл – это то, что **работа никуда не денется**, именно его надо выразить.

3) Здесь возможны **три решения:**
а) Ставим **присоединительную запятую,** обозначая неоднородность отношений.
б) Ставим **присоединительное тире,** обозначая взаимообусловленность сообщений.
 в) Ставим **разделительное тире или двоеточие,** подчеркивая взаимообусловленность сообщений и обозначая их направленность.

**Тире** – для схемы «причина–следствие»: так как работа не волк, то в лес не убежит.

**Двоеточие** – для схемы «следствие– причина»: работа не волк (а почему?), так как она не в лес не убежит.

4) **Что выбрать?**

Если поставить присоединительное тире, то при чтении  будет непонятно, какое оно: **разделительное или присоединительное.**

**Разделительное тире не очень желательно**, так как будет обозначена жесткая причинно-следственная связь предложений, а это тоже не является важным (работу можно сравнить с любым лесным животным).

**Если поставить двоеточие**, то на первый план выдвигается сравнение, которое по смыслу является попутным.

Поэтому  ставится **присоединительная запятая**, заменяющая **присоединительное тире,** при этом неоднородные отношения в БСП передаются разной структурой предложения (с однородными  отношениями не спутаешь).

При анализе использованы материалы из курса лекций Г.И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (2013).

Answer (score 1):

Как-то у вас все путано.

Во-первых, "варьируется" - очень неудачный термин. Каждый знак ставится по  ситуации или по мысли автора.

Во-вторых, нет никакой связи межу ситуациями с выбором между тире и скобками, двоеточием (то, что вы назвали "варьированием") с одной стороны и правилами оформления БСП с другой.

В отношении **замены парного тире на скобки** - да, такое возможно **при вставке**, если текст вставки достаточно самостоятельный и слабо связан с основным предложеннием.
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=300

Двоеточием, если вне БСП, часто заменяют тире (при перечислении) вопреки действующим правилам, но по сложившейся традиции, Розенталь о том косвенно упоминает, но это не настолько принципиальный момент. Действующие же правила тут.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/157-dvoe
Тут все строго, нет вариантов.

Вот с **запятой** сложнее. Обычно **вопрос** возникает **при выборе между просто тире и комбинацией запятая-тире**. Если опустить некоторые детали (с которыми, видимо, еще предстоит разобраться авторитетным специалистам), то запятая и тире ставится как сочетание знаков, если каждый из них ставится по своим основаниям. Отдельно оговаривается правило на это сочетание знаков при оформлении прямой речи. В остальных случаях обычно тире ставится "вместо" запятой. 
Хотя в целом ситуация остается несколько запутанной.
[О стыке тире и запятой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676)

Сочетание "запятая-тире" как единый знак постепенно выходит из употребления. 
Действующие правила тут.
http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/114/

*Всё это сказал только для того, чтобы навести ясность с тем, что вы назвали "варьированием"*. По сути какая-то альтернатива есть только при выборе между скобками и парным тире, остальное - либо редчайшие случаи, либо вообще вне рамок действующих правил.

Про **кавычки** - не знаю даже, о чем речь. **Тире кавычки никогда не заменяет**.

И это при том, что всё это к БСП не имеет никакого отношения. Правила оформления БСП в этой части очень просты.

> Тире между частями сложного бессоюзного предложения ставится при одном
>   из четырех условий:
>
> 1) если сложное предложение имеет значение противопоставления и между
>   частями можно вставить союз А или НО, например: Несколько раз
>   оглянулся – никого не было (Толстой);
>
> 2) если в первом предложении есть значение времени или условия и перед
>   ним можно вставить союз КОГДА или ЕСЛИ, например: Начальство хочет –
>   мы должны повиноваться (Гоголь);
>
> 3) если вторая часть предложения указывает следствие того, что описано
>   в первой части и перед ней можно вставить союз ТАК ЧТО, например:
>   Назвался груздем – полезай в кузов (Пословица);
>
> 4) в редких случаях тире используется также для обозначения быстрой
>   смены событий, например: Сыр выпал – с ним была плутовка такова
>   (Крылов).

http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185
Здесь можно спорить только по поводу счета - в других источниках для тире тоже насчитывают только три случая (объединяя второй и третий по счету "Грамоты").

> Существуют три случая, когда между частями сложного бессоюзного
>   предложения нужно поставить двоеточие:
>
> 1) если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой
>   части, например: В развитых странах средний класс решает исход
>   выборов: он составляет большинство населения. В это предложение можно
>   вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО;
>
> 2) если после первой части следует пояснение того, о чем идет речь в
>   первой части, например: Напишите план работы: что нужно закупить и
>   подготовить, с чего требуется начать, в какие сроки возможно
>   завершение проекта» или Как все московские ваш батюшка таков: желал бы
>   зятя он с звездами да с чинами (Грибоедов). В эти предложения между
>   частями можно вставить союз А ИМЕННО;
>
> 3) если вторая часть имеет значение дополнения, и перед ней можно
>   вставить союз ЧТО, например: Да я хотел вчера доложить: бороны
>   починить надо (Толстой). В некоторых случаях, кроме этого союза, в
>   предложение можно добавить и пропущенное сказуемое И УВИДЕЛ или И
>   УСЛЫШАЛ, например: Он заглянул в комнату: за столом сидел человек и
>   что-то быстро писал.

Там же - http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185.

Если даже это сложно, вот более адаптированный источник.
http://aprikablog.com/2015/07/tire-v-bessoyuznom-slozhnom-predlozhenii/

В остальных же случаях в БСП ставится запятая или точка с запятой.

Comment: А как же случай с прямым вопросом?

Comment: @RaynChar Уточните, пожалуйста, что такое "случай с прямым вопросом"?

Comment: Я спрашиваю: какая свинья?

Comment: А вы знаете, этот случай в правилах напрямую не описан. ))) Но вообще-то это  п. 2) в моей нумерации. Но не в этом дело, проблемы-то тут нету. Да есть рекомендация, как альтернатива прямой речи, ставить двоеточие, если вторая часть содержит вопрос. Но оно там всегда, запятая была бы ошибкой. Так что это опять-таки не "варьирование". Трудно что-то спутать. Но если действительно такое толкование недостаточно, посмотрите, например, здесь http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/305-znakiprepinaniyavsbessoyuznompredlogenii.html