# Надо ли закрывать запятой несогласованное определение перед тире?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, определения

Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди, со своими претензиями, своими амбициями(,) - это было бы еще хуже.

1. Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди, со своими претензиями, своими амбициями, - это было бы еще хуже.

   или:
2. Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди, со своими претензиями, своими амбициями - это было бы еще хуже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верен первый вариант, хотя, на мой взгляд, в нём переизбыток знаков.

Автор сделал (наверное) уточнение к "чужим людям" - *со своими претензиями, своими амбициями* - и оно обособляется по своим правилам, с двух сторон.

Тире тут тоже авторское. См. ***[§ 38. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142)***

Если же допустить, что знаки не авторские (к которым у нас доступа нет), то правильная пунктуация была бы такой:

*Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди со своими претензиями, своими амбициями - это было бы еще хуже;*

*Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди - со своими претензиями, своими амбициями - это было бы еще хуже;*

*Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди со своими претензиями, своими амбициями, это было бы еще хуже.*

Answer (score 2):

Если запятая и тире поставлены по разным причинам, то запятая не "поглощается".
У Вас именно такой случай.

Интересная дискуссия на тему "О стыке тире и запятой" [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676/%D0%9E-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9).

Answer (score 1):

1) **При уточнении:**  Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди, со своими претензиями, своими амбициями, — это было бы еще хуже.

**Формально вариант верен, а по сути нет**. Если  это уточнение, то надо использовать тире, так как однородные определения требуют перечислительной интонации (ее можно обозначить во вставной конструкции), а тире уже есть перед ЭТО (по рекомендации Розенталя). http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142

Ну нет у этого предложения интонационных и других возможностей, чтобы выразить и уточнение, и перечисление, и паузу перед местоимением, при этом нагромождение знаков  ничего не решает, а только ухудшает графику текста. Так что приходится чем-то пожертвовать ради краткости, выразительности и ясности речи (что особенно важно в публицистике).

2) Поэтому можно предложить **два варианта** (без уточнения и с уточнением):

Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди со своими претензиями и своими амбициями — это было бы еще хуже.

Если бы к нам пришли чужие люди, со своими претензиями и  своими амбициями,  то это было бы еще хуже.