# Чем тире отличается от единого знака "запятая и тире"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Не могу понять, чем отличаются эти знаки. Они передают разную интонацию? Или запятая и тире ― это просто графически более сильный знак (не знаю, можно ли так сказать).

И есть ли четкие правила для их употребления или хотя бы общие рекомендации?

Кажется, единый знак считается устаревающим, но, может быть, это только для определенных конструкций. Когда он является действительно необходимым или он всегда факультативный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Чем тире отличается от единого знака “запятая и тире”

Да многим отличается. Строго говоря, вообще ничего общего.

Запятая с тире как единый знак и как стечение знаков обсуждалась неоднократно.
Вот например.
[О стыке тире и запятой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676)

В этих случаях одиночное тире (без запятой) просто невозможно, скорее уж просто запятая.

> Они передают разную интонацию?

Нет, просто ставятся по разным основаниям.

> Или запятая и тире ― это просто графически более сильный знак (не знаю, можно ли так сказать).

Да, это "более сильный знак", он "разрывает" предложение на более крупные куски, внутри которых уже могут быть вложены части, ограничиваемые другими знаками. Но это совсем не "просто". Есть четкая логика для постановки этих знаков. И как сказал, у **тире** и **запятой с тире** она совершенно разная. Просто трудно понять, почему вы так вопрос поставили.

> И есть ли четкие правила для их употребления или хотя бы общие рекомендации?

Разумеется.
Запятая и тире как единый знак
http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_40.htm

Тире (тут много, целый раздел)
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91

> Кажется, единый знак считается устаревающим, но, может быть, это
>   только для определенных конструкций.

Нет. В тех пунктах, о которых говорит Розенталь, ничего устаревающего нет. Другое дело, что в классических произведениях можно найти "авторскую пунктуацию", где по современным нормам достаточно запятой.

> Когда он является действительно необходимым или он всегда факультативный?

В трех случаях, о которых говорит Розенталь, знак необходим.

> Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в
>   сложноподчиненном предложении:
>
> 1) перед главной частью, которой предшествует ряд однородных
>   придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на
>   две части (перед главной частью делается длительная пауза):Кто виноват
>   из них, кто прав, — судить не нам (Кр.); Делал ли что-нибудь для этого
>   Штольц, что делал и как делал, — мы этого не знаем (Добр.); Сколько их
>   было всего, этих людей, пришли ли они сюда случайно, долго ли
>   останутся здесь, — этого я вам сказать не могу;
>
> 2) перед словом, которое повторяется в той же части предложения
>   (придаточной или главной) для того, чтобы связать с ним дальнейшую
>   часть высказывания: Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич
>   чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди,
>   — все у него в руках (Л. Т.); И мысль, что он может, руководиться этим
>   интересом, что он для продажи этого леса будет искать примирения с
>   женой, — эта мысль оскорбляла его (Л. Т.); Жизнь его, начавшаяся (в
>   воспоминаниях так чудесно) громадной церковной папертью… и голосом
>   мамы, в котором тысячу раз знакомый блестел кремнистый путь и звезда
>   говорила со звездой, — эта жизнь с каждым своим часом наполнялась
>   новым, всё новым значением (Кат.).
>
> В других случаях тире ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную
>   часть, при «переломе» конструкции, перед словом это и т. д.: Однажды я
>   спросил себя: а что, если он вернётся, неожиданно явится к тебе, — ты
>   будешь рад?; Самое лучшее, что он мог сделать, — вовремя уйти; Что это
>   был за случай, в котором было столько неясного, — этого он припомнить
>   не мог; Единственное, что мне здесь нравится, — это старый тенистый
>   парк; Пусть я даже ошибаюсь, — что ж, ошибаться свойственно человеку;
>   Он замолчал, но не потому, что ему не хватало слов, — ему не хватало
>   дыхания; В смущении он говорил не то, что думал, — он произносил
>   первые пришедшие на ум слова.

http://old-rozental.ru/paragraph.php?file=pt_40.htm

И в довершение. Все сказанное касается именно запятой и тире как единого знака. Есть еще несколько случаев **стечения** этих знаков. 
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=176
Об этом случае нужно говорить отдельно, ибо, при кажущейся простоте формулировки ("стечением запятой и тире считается постановка их по разным основаниям"), на практиве возникает вопрос "поглощения" одного знака другим.

> Когда мы меняем запятую на тире и паузой делим предложение на две
>   части, то разве это нельзя читать переломом интонации?

Ничего не понял. Мы "меняем" запятую на тире в  том и только том случае, если это требуется правилами пунктуации. Да, одним из таких условий является смена интонации, паузу можно рассматривать как частный случай смены (хотя музыкантам, например, это может показаться странным).

Но для использования запятой и тире как единого знака (если вопрос в этом) такого факта явно недостаточно. Посмотрите, у Розенталя есть два четко описанных случая

> 1) перед главной частью, которой предшествует ряд однородных
>   придаточных, если подчеркивается распадение сложного предложения на
>   две части
>
> 2) перед словом, которое повторяется в той же части предложения
>   (придаточной или главной) для того, чтобы связать с ним дальнейшую
>   часть высказывания

Одной запятой в этих случаях недостаточно, а одно тире (без запятой) противоречило бы синтаксису.

ЕСть еще и третий случай, где говорится прямо о переломе интонации

> других случаях тире ставится после запятой, закрывающей придаточную
>   часть, при «переломе» конструкции, перед словом это и т. д.:

Его можно трактовать расширительно, но на то все равно воля автора.

> И еще : почему Розенталь в следующих предложениях "ставит" тире, а не
>   запятую и тире...

Тире с запятой тут максимум альтернативный вариант пунктуации. Тут скорее надо будет спросить, на каком основании использовать тире с запятой, - у того, кто такие знаки поставит. Предложения в обоих частях достаточно простые, императивных оснований для тире с запятой как единого знака просто нет.

**Однородных придаточных** там нет.

Comment: Спасибо большое Вам за ответ, можно  задать ещё вопрос. Мне еще пока не очень ясно,  что такое "перелом интонации". Когда мы меняем запятую на тире и  паузой делим предложение на две части, то разве это нельзя читать переломом интонации? И еще : почему Розенталь  в следующих предложениях "ставит" тире, а не запятую и тире (там есть слово ЭТО и однородные придаточные).Как он добрался сюда — уж этого никак не мог он понять. Голова ли думает, сердце ли чувствует или руки перевёртывают стаканы — всё покрывается равными плесками (Г.);

Comment: @Polina  у вас много вопросов, в комментариях не поместится. Я отвечу в тексте самого ответа, а вообще можно и отдельный вопрос задать.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я задам отдельный вопрос, так удобнее.