# Почему нет запятой после придаточного перед тире в БСП?

Tags: пунктуация, придаточное-предложение, бессоюзное

***Странно, что Стенина не приметила его (портрет) раньше — впрочем, она редко заглядывала в комнату Евгении...***

В современной литературе придаточные предложения и определительные обороты не всегда закрываются запятой перед тире, хотя в данном случае придаточное явно относится к первой части  БСП.

Какое правило регулирует постановку или отсутствие запятой?

У Розенталя есть материал, посвященный этой теме:
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=175#pp175

Там нет примера с БСП, но в  то же время рассматриваются различные конструкции, в которых придаточное закрывается запятой:

***Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали*** (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.

***Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не размахивал руками, — первый признак некоторой скрытности характера*** (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения, тире поставлено перед своеобразным приложением к предшествующим словам, имеет присоединительный оттенок;

Comment: С этим вообще большая путаница. Вопрос сколько раз поднимался - столько же и угасал. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676

Answer (score 1):

Основанием для такой запятой (вместо точки или иного знака) обычно становится продолжение главного предложения после придаточного (= придаточное внутри главного):

> Странно, что Стенина не приметила его раньше, очень непонятно и
> досадно.

По всей видимости, этим случаем двусторонее отделение придаточного запятой (с "закрытием") исчерпывается:

> *Придаточное предложение отделяется от главного запятой или выделяется*
> *запятыми с двух сторон, если находится **внутри главного предложения**...*
>
> (Розенталь, §107 http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/49.htm )

В нашем случае после окончания СПП к нему присоединяется *независимое* предложение - через свой знак (вместо тире могла быть точка с запятой или просто точка, либо одиночная запятая на дополнительных основаниях присоединения).

**P.S.** В рамках пунктуации при СПП Розенталь рассматривает "запятую + тире" для случаев прямой отсылки (через местоимение или повторение слова) к содержанию СПП из присоединяемого высказывания, а также для случая повторяющихся придаточных, к которым адресуются через тире. У нас же присоединяется высказывание без прямых отсылок к элементам предложения.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=144#pp144

(§ 40. Запятая и тире в сложноподчиненном предложении)

Comment: *По всей видимости, этим случаем двусторонее отделение придаточного запятой (с "закрытием") исчерпывается:* - чудовищная отсебятина. Во-первых, здесь идет речь не о том, что запятая стоит (или должна стоять) не **вместо**, а наряду с другим знаком. Во-вторых, Розенталь не говорит ничего о том, что рассматриваемым случаем список ограничивается. Да и примеров, когда тире и запятая мирно сосуществует, причем не как единый знак, масса.

Comment: Alex_ander, я добавила в вопрос материал из Розенталя о сочетании знаков, но там нет БСП. Очень хотелось бы найти у Розенталя или Лопатина именно такой пример ( тире в БСП).

Comment: Так есть же БСП: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=152#pp152

Answer (score 0):

> Почему нет запятой после придаточного перед тире в БСП?

Считаю это ошибкой. Знесь просто нет причин опускать эту запятую. 
Случаи "поглощения" запятой **одиночным** тире нигде не нормированы.
Собственно, все, что я знал по этому поводу, изложено по ссылке в моем комментарии.

Но Alex_ander своей отсылкой к Розенталю навел меня на мысль о причинах постоянного повторения подобного. 
Судя по всему, указанный пункт у Розенталя неверно интерпретируются даже опытными корректорами-редакторами.

> Запятая и тире в качестве единого знака препинания ставятся в
>   сложноподчиненном предложении:

Здесь ключевое слово "в качестве единого знака". Под единым знаком понимается случай, когда для этого знака существует единая, общая причина. И тогда - да, список случаев у Розенталя можно (хотя и с большой оговоркой) считать более или менее исчерпывающим. Наш случай в этот перечень не попадает.

Но дело-то все в том, что в разбираемом примере речь вовсе не идет о едином знаке. Запятая и тире ставятся по совершенно разным мотивам (закрытие придаточного и переход ко второй части БСП соответственно). И вот в этом-то случае никаких правил для того, чтобы опустить тире, не предусмотрено. Хотя, как уже сказал семь лет назад, правила такие постоянно пытаются вывести, но, на мой взгляд, безуспешно - просто в силу бессистемности подобных попыток.

Итак. Полагаю, запятая нужна, а ошибочная пунктуация связана с ошибочным представлением о понятии "единый знак".

@Sharon, по понятным (надеюсь) причинам, вынужден перенести сюда комментарий

> Здесь запятая вообще "мешает", так как последнее замечание
>    относится к придаточному.

Здесь вообще невозможно однозначно установить синтаксис.

> Итак, "закрывающая запятая" соответствует существующей норме, но
>    разве эти нормы абсолютно неприкасаемы?

А вот тут я вынужден ответить со всей определенностью. 
Нормы "прикасаемы", но это не значит, что их надо нарушать просто по прихоти или незнанию. "Норма" о том, что парная запятая должна оставаться парной, действительно основополагающая, хотя никак это и не сформулировано. Такой подход облегчает распознавание синтаксиса, да и снимает целый ряд потенциальных двусмысленностей. 
Можно сказать так, что запятая "поглощается" только знаком более высокого "приоритета" - точкой, точкой с запятой, восклицательным и вопросительным знаками. Одиночное тире - это знак того же "уровня", что и запятая.

> Это я к тому, что запятые здесь случайно не забывают поставить.

Честно говоря, совершенно неубедительно. Да и вообще именно про АСТ ходят весьма нелестные слухи. Понимаю, там не один редактор, но реверанс какой-то художественной авторессы не впечатляет, сейчас мода такая - благодарить редактора непойми за что.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я в свой вопрос добавила примеры из Розенталя, где он рассматривает сочетание знаков. Я думаю, что по основным (классическим) правилам запятая должна там стоять. Но мне кажется, что существует новая тенденция, хотя и ненормированная, в соответствии с которой запятая не ставится. Я часто встречаю в современной литературе подобные примеры. Хотелось бы услышать мнение редакторов и корректоров - что они об этом думают.

Answer (score 0):

*Это был портрет, и примечательный. Странно, что Стенина не приметила его раньше — впрочем, она редко заглядывала в комнату Евгении, а может, Юлька повесила портрет недавно.*

Я воспринимаю часть предложения после тире как вставную конструкцию. Возможно, автору не хотелось ставить скобки, чтобы не было резкого разграничения предложения, и он использовал тире. А запятая "просто забылась"? Я бы ее, конечно, же поставила.

Интересно, что в книге нашлись и другие предложения (в пределах одной страницы), которые, по моему мнению, также требуют постановки запятой.

*Среди тарелок с объедками лежал, в соответствии с жанром, весёлый череп, будто бы вгрызающийся зубами в раскрытую книгу(,) — ни дать ни взять прилежный ученик в ночь перед решающим экзаменом.

А Стенина побрела в свою двести шестьдесят восьмую, на глазах превращаясь из Веры в Веру Викторовну(,) — каждый шаг добавлял серьёзности, надменности, опыта.*

Возможно, это тенденция такая — авторское упрощение пунктуации? Не одобряю.

Comment: Римма, я тут заинтересовалась вашим "не одобряю". А вот в таком предложении вы бы поставили запятую: " Юлька увидит, каким он стал - сразу прибежит.  А тебе опять останутся опилки да отжимки". Похоже на БСП, второе предложение неполное.  Нужна здесь запятая по правилам?

Comment: Да, я бы поставила запятую. _Юлька увидит, каким он стал, — сразу прибежит._ (Юлька увидит — сразу прибежит.) Далее — почти сразу — идет ещё одно _спорное_ ("тенденциальное") предложение, в котором я бы однозначно поставила запятую. _Они сидели в кухне, плотно прикрыв дверь(,) — запах коровинских роз к вечеру стал уж совсем нестерпимым._ Авторская (особенная!) пунктуация должна быть последовательной, а не избирательной.

Comment: @Sharon Удивительно, что Вы заинтересовались **чьим-то** мнением... Теперь вопрос Вам: а в следующем предложении КАК объясить пунктуацию? _Ольга смеялась вместе со всеми, но глаза у неё оставались злыми. **Они похожи на семечки, — и цветом, и формой, решила вдруг Вера.**_

Comment: Римма, я же по простоте душевной заинтересовалась, а вы иронизируете. Вот никто меня не любит, а я так стараюсь  быть белой и пушистой (хотя и  немного разноцветная, конечно).  А теперь о деле. В предложении (1)  тире РАЗДЕЛИТЕЛЬНОЕ, основная тема условно-следственная:  как увидит – сразу прибежит. Это тире центральное, очень важное, не надо его запятыми разбавлять. В предложении (2) тире ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНОЕ, тема первой части закончена, взаимообусловленности нет, а есть дополнительное замечание. Там закрывающая запятая не помешает.

Comment: А вот предложение (3) – самое проблемное.  Речь Верочки ввиду ее состояния изображается прерывистой,  мысли в голову приходят неожиданно, с паузами, а только тире или только запятая такую паузу не обозначат. Поэтому могу вам сказать со всей уверенностью: авторская пунктуация НЕ ДОЛЖНА быть последовательной, а должна быть разнообразной,  выразительной.  Стиль писателя – как краски у художника,  каждый эпизод нужно этими красками прописать.  И  знаки пунктуации   здесь очень важны, так как напрямую связаны с интонационным рисунком речи (а не только с правилами, как обычно думают).

Comment: Хотел бы разъяснить пунктуацию. Закономерности, увы, обратны вашей, Sharon, логике (хотя она рациональна): если части связаны - запятая есть, если не связаны - запятой не будет. (3) Есть скрытая связь некого "определения понятия". Она станет очевидной, если изменить предложение: Они похожи на семечки - это решение Веры. Но тип связи при этом не меняется, просто выражался глаголом. (2) Там расшифровывается причина. У Розенталя не видел примеров с причинной связью. Это функция двоеточия, а не смыслового тире - думаю, именно это причина отсутствия запятой. Автор решил просто усилить запятую тире.

Answer (score 0):

В первом примере часть после тире не относиться напрямую к слову `странно`, а просто продолжается повествование. Там нет никаких следственных связей или определения. Если были бы - то запятая обязательна. Тут запятая просто меняется на тире для усиления.

Считаю, что отсутствие запятой в этом случае корректно и, более того, что наличие запятой не факультативно.

Довольно часто запятая просто меняется на тире для усиления. Иначе бы мы почти всегда видели тире вместе с запятой, а это, наоборот, редко (среди всех случаев с тире).

Во втором примере присутствует следственная связь, что обуславливает необходимость запятой.

В третьем примере есть определение (связь) - поэтому запятая обязательна. Подтверждает Розенталь в § 40 (хоть и предложение из § 64). На мой взгляд, это наиболее частый случай использования тире с запятой.

Да и вообще - можно разделить это правило на смысловые категории, используя довольно непростые примеры Розенталя, чего он не делает.

Если есть другие неочевидные примеры, то было бы интересно взглянуть.

Если интересно, то расскажу, зачем вообще используется тире вместе с запятой и почему запятая всегда не поглощается тире (хотя намёк уже дал).

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо всем за ответы, и я попробую высказать **свое мнение.**

1) При постановке знаков препинания должны использоваться правила. Правило (в официальном источнике) — это **закон, который нужно соблюдать,** только такая пунктуация считается **нормативной**.

2) Я просмотрела  примеры у Розенталя и в ПАС и убедилась, что в наших классических правилах **независимая постановка знаков препинания является основным принципом**. Розенталь вообще вроде бы не использует такой термин, как поглощение запятой.

3) Но тогда возникает такой "крамольный" вопрос: **а почему верен этот принцип, какая идея лежит в его основе?** В конце концов, нам важно, чтобы знаки препинания помогали нам правильно определить структуру предложения, это их главное назначение.

Допустим, не поставлю я запятую:

***Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи — и мы оба замолчали***. Тире делит предложение на две смысловые части.  Запятая, закрывающая придаточное предложение, оказалась на границе этих частей, но зачем она там?  Ведь мы же не ставим запятую в конце предложения перед точкой.

***Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не размахивал руками — первый признак некоторой скрытности характера.***

Здесь запятая вообще "мешает", так как последнее замечание относится к придаточному.

4) Итак, "закрывающая запятая" соответствует существующей норме, но разве эти нормы **абсолютно неприкасаемы?**

Нормы могут меняться, если общество сочтет их устаревшими и  не соответствующими современным потребностям письма. И возможно, **новые приемы пунктуации** должны воздействовать на эти существующие нормы **по факту.**

Поэтому **будем пока наблюдать** за этим явлением.

5) **Примечание**

Роман Анны Матвеевой "Завидное чувство Веры Стениной", Москва, издательство АСТ, редакция Елены Шубиной, 2015, литературный редактор Галина Беляева.

Интересная  проза о современной жизни (много психологии и совсем чуть-чуть фантастики), прекрасный язык, тщательно проработанный стиль. Автор благодарит лучшую в мире редакцию **за профессионализм.**

Это я к тому, что запятые здесь *случайно* не забывают поставить.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97637/discussion-on-answer-by-sharon-------).

Answer (score 0):

Это ответ на комментарий

1) **Три принципа пунктуации**

Сначала небольшое лирическое отступление, так что не судите строго. Обычно я очень кратко касаюсь интонации, так как участники этого не любят и не понимают. Все наши учебники по правописанию ориентированы **на грамматику** с очень давних времен (еще от Ломоносова).

Но в 20 веке были сформулированы **три основные принципы пунктуаци**и (семантика, грамматика и интонация), и это было большим достижением – разобраться в этой «мешанине». Но дальше дело не пошло, правила остались такими же, какими были, только Розенталь иногда всё-таки вспоминает про интонацию.

**Но зачем нам знать эти принципы**, как их применить на практике? Мы все художники слова, и мы хотим что-то в нашей речи изобразить (это семантика, принцип первый). В руках у нас карандаш (грамматика, принцип второй), перед нами ящик с красками (интонационно-структурная модель, принцип третий).

Информационная революция сделала нашу жизнь другой,  мир вдруг расширился, стал бесконечным. Чтобы описать его, нам нужны не новые правила письма – **нам нужно осмыслить и дополнить правила существующие,** то есть нормировать и свести в систему то, что уже реально (по факту) существует в литературе.

К примеру, нам **катастрофически не хватает нормированных правил для оформления прямой речи,** по существующим правилам даже классику XIX века не запишешь, а мы уже в XXI веке живем. Сама речь меняется, и способы ее передачи требуются более разнообразные. А у нас по-прежнему в нормированных правилах рассматриваются четыре школьных схемы да два-три дополнения к ним. Волей-неволей приходится пользоваться ненормированными средствами.

2) **Анализ предложения**

***Они похожи на семечки, — и цветом, и формой, решила вдруг Вера.***

Предложение нестандартное, а какое стандартное, чтобы по правилам можно было написать?  ***«Они похожи на семечки по цвету и форме», — вдруг  решила Вера.***

И это всё, только две части, на три части предложение не делится. Присоединительный оборот сюда не помещается, да еще конфликтует с наречием «вдруг» по смыслу, если их разъединить. И обычное оформление прямой речи не для этого эпизода. **Вот и решай задачи, если ты действительно художник.**

**Вера – искусствовед** (в  «настоящих» картинах она чувствует жизнь, движение, персонажи разговаривают между собой).  Рисовать по-настоящему она не умеет, но зато представляет всё окружающее нарисованным, а в изображенный момент чувства еще обостряются.  **Сначала** подумала, что глаза похожи на семечки, **пото**м объяснила себе почему, добавила цвет и форму.

**Это смысл предложения, а как его изобразить?**  Используем смысловые блоки, разделяя их  единым знаком «запятая и тире».  Слова автора оформляем вводным предложением. Наречие «вдруг»  относим к обороту, теперь он на месте.

3) **Приложение**

**Эпизод из книги** (*чтобы совсем понятно было*)

Надо сказать, что прием несобственно-прямой речи автор использует постоянно, то есть от авторской позиции свободно переходит к  позиции персонажа.  Текст получается, многоплановым, живописным, действительно воспринимается как живая картина.

*Бакулина вновь пошарила в своей торбе и вытащила оттуда на сей раз камамбер — тоже предназначенный одному человеку, но…*

*— Бедный твой человек, — веселилась Стенина. — Остался и без сыра, и без вина! .*.

*Ольга смеялась вместе со всеми, но глаза у неё оставались злыми. **Они похожи на семечки, — и цветом, и формой, решила вдруг Вера.** На пьяную голову всё стало таким понятным!*