# Нужно ли закрывать запятой придаточное в заданном предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, сложное-предложение

**Из современной художественной литературы:**

*Пять минут назад Вере позвонила Юлькина дочь Евгения — годом старше Лары. Кричала в трубку, плакала. Сказала, **что не может дозвониться до матери** — та и вправду находилась с мобильником в сложных отношениях.*

В предложении три предикативных основы, поэтому это **[сложная синтаксическая конструкция](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=136#pp136).**

Такие предложения отнюдь не редкость, поэтому хотелось бы узнать: **есть ли правило** на эту тему у Розенталя или в ПАС под ред. Лопатина?

Но если такого правила нет, то **как решить вопрос** о постановке или отсутствии запятой.

Спасибо.

Comment: У вас давно был вопрос на эту тему. К сожалению, нет зацепок, чтобы найти.

Comment: Я тоже не помню, меня эта тема давно интересовала, поэтому могла спрашивать. Вот еще интересный вопрос https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474472/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-тире-в-следующих-предложениях  Мне кажется, что метод блоков  может быть универсальным решением в этой теме.

Comment: Это правило про очень большие предложения. Не надо его применять на маленьких. Блок — это что-то большое. Можно просто сказать, что в правилах такого нет. Розенталь только сказал, когда употребляется тире с запятой, а надо было ещё сказать, когда запятая поглощается. Но он это не потянул. Всегда оставлять запятую явно не вариант.

Comment: Я снимаю ваше ограничение для блоков (я же новатор, мне это легко) и объясняю с их помощью все конструкции с уже существующим решением ( у того же Розенталя или в текстах). Если  они действительно будут так решаться, то ключик найден)

Comment: У меня тоже нужна, я расширяю понятие блоков.

Comment: Это не будет всегда работать правильно. Возьмите примеры Розенталя с запятой, расширьте первую часть до сложного предложения, типа блок получается. И что, запятую можно убирать? Нет, на пунктуацию не влияет. Это лишь общее правило, которым можно попробовать что-то оправдать (если начальник придерётся). Никак не подходит как метод решения.

Comment: Ладно, Олид, я думаю, что будет. Но публиковать этот метод не буду, не тот состав форума. Его удобно попробовать на предложении из ссылки.

Comment: Ладно, я верю..

Comment: Ладно, вот тот вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/454226 Там секрет (про встречу знаков) частично раскрыт (дан большой намёк). Alex_ander тоже хорошо сказал, он употребил одно очень важное слово, которое выделено.

Comment: Вы тогда меня ещё всерьёз не воспринимали и на мои ответы не реагировали.

Comment: Потом договорим. ладно? Сейчас времени нет.

Comment: Ну, перечитаете, потом скажете, если будет что сказать.

Answer (score 1):

*Сказала, **что не может дозвониться до матери** — та и вправду находилась с мобильником в сложных отношениях.*

Такие предложения действительно являются **проблемными.**

С одной стороны, придаточное в общем случае **закрывается запятой**, а тире ставится в БСП. Это независимая постановка знаков, и в результате мы видим **сочетание** запятой и тире.

С другой стороны, точно так же выглядит **единый знак** запятая и тире, а он здесь точно ни к чему. Единый знак  имеет свою область применения и ставится обычно в более распространенных сложных конструкциях при особых условиях.

Поэтому используем **правило Лопатина** о постановке знаков в сложных предложениях: § 132. *В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся на крупные логико-синтаксические блоки, которые сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в которых один из блоков оказывается сложным предложением, **на стыке блоков** ставятся знаки препинания, указывающие **на взаимоотношения блоков,** при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании.*

Итак, у нас **два блока**, причем второй блок имеет **пояснительный** характер. Поэтому между блоками ставится **только тире**, и оно как бы поглощает "пограничную" запятую.

Comment: Вторая(часть)  или второй (блок)? О чем речь? Вроде речь о блоке.

Comment: Да, я имела в виду второй блок.