# Нужна ли запятая перед тире? Проблема с пунктуацией

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

На земле лорда по имени Гарридан нет урожая из-за засухи. Крестьяне голодают. Гарридан пытается помочь им.

> Немало денег Гарридан потратил, ища совета у мудрецов, а на остатки средств скупил все излишки зерна, что смог найти в соседних владениях. **Он сказал мне, что подумывает о продаже замка и всего своего имущества(,) — лишь бы выжили люди**. Если бы только удалось собрать хоть небольшой урожай, они были бы спасены.

Нужна ли запятая перед тире в выделенном предложении? С одной стороны, запятая закрывала бы придаточное предложение. С другой стороны, фраза после тире по смыслу больше относится к придаточному, чем к главному предложению.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая ставится: *Он сказал мне, что подумывает о продаже замка и всего своего имущества, — **лишь бы выжили люди.***

Надо закрыть придаточное, так как заключительная часть относится **ко всему СПП.**

**Пояснение**

1. Тесную связь мы видим в таком предложении: *Я подумываю о продаже замка и всего своего имущества — **лишь бы выжили люди**.* Это БСП, во второй части названа причина такого решения.
2. В заданном предложении идет **пересказ** (он сказал), а потом следует **ПРИСОЕДИНИТЕЛЬНАЯ** конструкция: *(**по его мнению**), лишь бы выжили люди.* Поэтому тесной связи уже нет, это две самостоятельные части предложения.
3. Сравним (**точка с запятой**):  *Он сказал мне, что подумывает о продаже замка и всего своего имущества; **по его мнению**, лишь бы выжили люди.*  Или так (**единый знак**): *Он сказал мне, что подумывает о продаже замка и всего своего имущества, — **по его мнению**, лишь бы выжили люди.*

В обоих случаях мы подчеркнутой паузой обозначаем относительную **самостоятельность** двух частей предложения. Соответственно, в **заданном** предложении закрывающая запятая и тире тоже воспринимаются как **обозначение** подчеркнутой паузы.

4. Если решать задачу через **БЛОКИ**, то на границе блоков у нас единый знак, а не просто тире. На блоки мы делим сложное предложение с **тремя** предикативными основами.

Comment: Так здесь же не вставка. К чему эти размышления?

Comment: Вы забыли свой вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474885

Comment: Да, но это обсудим потом. Здесь я обЪясняю, почему нет тесной связи, на основании чего мы закрываем придаточное предложение.

Comment: Здесь похожее на то, что в вашем вопросе. А такую связь анализируют, когда вставка... В оригинале тоже как бы причина такого решения (несмотря на то, что пересказ).

Comment: В моем предложении единый рассказчик (воспоминания автора, там тесная связь). А здесь, как мне думается, обычный пересказ в двух частях (он сказал, по его мнению) Можно вообще на два предложения разделить. Разница даже по интонации чувствуется (здесь пауза именно подчеркнутая, а там присоединительная).

Comment: Похоже, что "лишь бы выжили люди" добавляет от себя рассказчик, тогда да, отличается. Но это не вставка, так что не надо анализировать, что к чему относится. Вашу модификацию тоже можно на два предложения разделить.

Comment: Я не говорю, что это вставка, но говорю о том, что нет тесной связи. И предлагаю решение через блоки. Тогда сочетание знаков можно представить как единый знак.

Comment: Нет, надо сказать, что это роли не играет, потому что не вставка. К чему здесь теснота связи? Единый знак не подходит. Если изменить, то может подойти. Единый знак не просто для паузы. Тире — когда следствие, двоеточие — когда причина, раскрытие, а единый знак... Трёх основ мало, думаю, хотя бы пять надо.

Comment: Единый знак не так прост, я его упоминаю для анализа. Главное – пауза должна быть обозначена. Тут вопрос вообще дискуссионный (недавно был похожий на форуме). Когда мы включаем  сложное предложение (БСП)  в состав СПП (значение изъяснения), то идет перестройка интонации БСП.  То, что было обозначено тире, будет читаться с короткой паузой, а здесь этого  не нужно. Нам нужна именно подчеркнутая пауза.  Но в простом объяснении мы просто говорим: да, надо закрыть придаточное.

Comment: Но он гораздо проще, чем стык запятой и тире. Он, как тире и двоеточие, указывает на смысловые отношения. А пауза — лишь следствие.

Comment: Указывает на смысл, разумеется. Да только знак один, а смысловые варианты могут быть разные. Поэтому увеличенная пауза – это серьезный ориентир. Это то, как мы воспринимаем речь.

Comment: Ну не много вариантов. У Розенталя только два заметил. Например, если нет причин для постановки двоеточия, то увеличение паузы не аргумент. Так и с единым знаком.

Comment: Мне так не кажется. Знак сложный и интересный, просто его пока мало изучали.

Comment: У Розенталя достаточно примеров для его понимания, чего нельзя сказать о стыке знаков. Чисто для увеличения паузы его нельзя ставить!