# Совершенно не понимаю постановку некоторых знаков препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь

Текст: *"Каллиграф не допустил бы этих росчерков или,  лучше сказать,  этих попыток расчеркнуться, вот этих недоконченных полухвостиков, - замечаете, - а в целом,  посмотрите,  оно составляет ведь характер,  и,  право,  вся тут военно-писарская душа проглянула:  разгуляться бы и хотелось,  и талант просится,  да воротник военный туго на крючок стянут, дисциплина и в почерке вышла,  прелесть!"*

Больше всего интересует часть с выделением слова *"замечаете"* - почему оно отделено с обеих сторон тире? Еще есть смутные сомнения по поводу знака после слов *"крючок стянут"*. То есть сомнений особых нет, поскольку в оригинальном тексте стоит именно запятая, хотя я бы при письме употребила все же другой знак препинания.
Заранее благодарю за разъяснения.

Comment: Плюсик - от меня, но только за основной вопрос. Про "другой знак препинания" хорошо бы  вам уточнить...

Comment: Не знаю даже... На самом деле я уже пришла к мнению, что любой другой знак кроме запятой перегрузил бы и без того громоздкую конструкцию данного предложения. А то мне уже посоветовали писать собственного "Идиота" и расставлять знаки по своему усмотрению (при этом я не нападала на авторский стиль Достоевского). Скорее дело в том, что мне показалось будто последующая часть как бы разъясняет предыдущую, но еще одно двоеточие потянуло бы этот Титаник на дно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Непростой вопрос на самом деле. И дело тут не в авторской пунктуации Достоевского (а он как и многие писатели конца XIX - начала XX века - вплоть до Горького - любил авторское тире), а в понимании синтаксиса этой фразы и тогдашних подходов к пунктуации.

> Больше всего интересует часть с выделением слова "замечаете" - почему оно отделено с обеих сторон тире?

Вы не совсем правильно ставите вопрос.
**Тут, полагаю, не тире с двух сторон, а два раза тире с запятой как единый знак препинания.** Такое встречается у классиков.

Иначе трактовать трудно. В двух словах объяснить не могу, пишу подробно.

Тут вот в чем дело.
Только в одном случае, втором - после "замечаете", есть некоторые основания полагать, что эти знаки поставлены по разным мотивам: тире для выделения вставной конструкции, а запятая как знак разделения частей сложносочиненного предложения - хотя такая трактовка и спорна.

А вот в первом - перед "замечаете" - для запятой перед тире нет оснований: тут **по современным правилам** либо тире, либо запятая. Или, другими словами, такую запятую тире "поглощает". Про такое "поглощение" - тут: [О стыке тире и запятой](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/7676). Поглощение это - само по себе вопрос дискуссионный, но в отношении нашего случая все прозрачно. Вставная конструкция выделяется (или отделяется) либо тире - либо запятой, а других мотивов для запятой **перед** "замечаете" нет.

Понимание тире с запятой как ***единого парного знака препинания*** снимает эту проблему. Такую пунктуацию можно считать устаревшей, однако у авторов XIX века она была весьма популярна.

> Примечание 2. При оформлении вставных конструкций в середине
> предложения встречается употребление запятой и тире как единого знака
> препинания: Вы садитесь в коляску, — это так приятно после вагона, — и
> катите по степной дороге (Ч.). Такое выделение для современных текстов
> не характерно.

Лопатин. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации, § 97.
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=126

> Еще есть смутные сомнения по поводу знака после слов "крючок стянут" <...> Я бы при письме употребила все же другой знак препинания.

Вообще-то вам стоило бы назвать этот другой знак, чтобы отвечающие голову не ломали...
Хотя здесь трудно найти адекватную замену для такой запятой. Двоеточие не походит, поскольку трактовка "вторая часть разъясняет первую" крайне сомнительна, а тире означало бы период, то есть разделяло бы фразу на две части совсем не там, где следует по смыслу. Да и не рекомендуется  в одной фразе одновременно использовать непарное и парное тире (включая парное тире с запятой как единый знак).

Впрочем, возможно, что у вас какие-то свои мотивы... Я их не вижу.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129405/discussion-on-answer-by-behemothus------).

Answer (score 2):

**Ответ третий**  (строго по теме в соответствии с правилом Розенталя), пункт 4. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=125#pp125

Цитата из вопроса:  *«Больше всего интересует часть с выделением слова "замечаете"  – **почему оно отделено с обеих сторон тире?»***

**Итак, все о слове «замечаете».**

Слово «замечаете»  оформлено как  **вставная конструкция** и по правилам обособляется **двумя тире**. Обособить его запятыми в сложном предложении с большим количеством собственных знаков было бы затруднительно.

В зависимости от структуры на месте «разрыва» основного предложения, помимо тире, могут быть **еще запятые**.

В данном случае  **обоснованной является вторая  запятая**, которая ставится перед союзом А (так называемая перенесенная запятая), а для постановки первой запятой оснований нет.

В то же время  Розенталь говорит о возможности своеобразной **симметрии знаков.** Именно такую симметрию мы видим в данном случае.

Можно предположить, что у Достоевского **симметричная постановка запятых** уравновешивает конструкцию так, чтобы вставка не относилась к левой части, а произносилась между двумя фразами.

Это трактовка авторской пунктуации **в соответствии с современными нормами,** если вопрос был об этом.

Comment: Спасибо, так для меня, пожалуй, более понятно.

Answer (score 1):

*Каллиграф не допустил бы этих росчерков или, лучше сказать, этих попыток расчеркнуться, вот этих недоконченных полухвостиков – **замечаете**, //–  а в целом, **посмотрите**, оно составляет ведь характер, //и, **право**, вся тут военно-писарская душа проглянула: разгуляться бы и хотелось, и талант просится, да воротник военный туго на крючок стянут, //дисциплина и в почерке вышла, **прелесть**!*

Это **мысли-впечатления**, еще не оформленные нужным образом и до конца не продуманные. Поэтому и следуют они одна за другой, не останавливаясь, не разделяясь на отдельные фрагменты –  и поэтому **только запятые, только бессоюзная связь!**

Единственный сильный знак – это **двоеточие** в третьей части, но и там его присутствие вполне оправдано, так как связано с раскрытием  этого удивительного феномена – "военно-писарской души".

Все эти впечатления, а также соучастие в прочтении автора и его собеседника надо было передать на письме, и, пожалуй. это **единственно правильная форма**. Текст можно разделить на четыре части, и каждая обозначена обращением к читателю (замечаете, посмотрите, право, прелесть). Здесь я полностью на стороне писателя – мастерство видно во всем!

Я бы по современным правилам исправила бы оформление вставки **«замечаете».** Если убрать **первую запятую**, то вставка будет относиться к первой части, что более логично.

**ПОЯСНЕНИЕ** (о вставке ***замечаете***)

Постановка одного ил двух тире у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Пункт 4.
2) перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения: Он посмотрел на пепелище, которое окружало его, — какой ужас! — и руки бессильно опустились у него — запятая закрывает придаточную часть сложноподчиненного предложения;

В тексте у Достоевского **нет причин для постановки первой запятой**, если только для симметрии. Там  перечисляются однородные члены (линейная конструкция без обособлений). **Как объяснить эту запятую?**

Конечно, тогда еще не было правил Розенталя, но автор по интуиции мог понять, что отсутствие запятой относит вставку **к предыдущей части**. А иначе (при обособлении запятыми) она просто **разделяет фрагменты** текста. Здесь только два решения.

Comment: *Это мысли-впечатления, еще не оформленные нужным образом и до конца не продуманные.* - забавно. Откуда там непродуманные мысли? Вы полагаете, что Кн. Мышкин - идиот истинный, в медицинском смысле?

Comment: И почему вы никак не оговариваете опущенную вами запятую (перед первым тире) при цитировании в начале ответа? А ведь она ломает ваши доводы. === А, понял. Вы берете на себе смелость редактировать авторский стиль Достоевского по современным правилам. Причем додумываете за него не только пунктуацию, но еще и смысл... "Не по чину берешь!", не находите?))))

Answer (score 1):

Второй ответ

**Знаки препинания нужно понимать обязательно** – может быть, даже не разумом, а сердцем.

*– Вот это, – разъяснял князь **с чрезвычайным удовольствием и одушевлением**, – это собственная подпись игумена Пафнутия…*

И это **ключевые слова данного фрагмента**. Волшебство писателя состоит в том, что он позволяет нам перенестись в другое время, увидеть происходящее своими глазами. И почувствовать **воодушевление героя**, а иногда и весь его характер. Вчитайтесь в строки – **именно в том виде, как они записаны,** – и вы почувствуете  взволнованность, воодушевление и заинтересованность его души.

И тогда  будто сами станете на мгновение князем Мышкиным, начнете думать и говорить его словами. Перед нами  **не выверенная мыслью правильная речь**, он волнуется и торопится сказать главное. **Ему хочется увлечь и вас** своим предметом – ведь по почерку можно понять характер человека, прочитать что-то тайное в его душе. Разве это не увлекательно!

Вот и записывает Достоевский эту быструю, эмоциональную речь, **используя те знаки, которые могут ее выразить.** А наши знаки – это нотные знаки, об этом надо помнить всегда. Почему «замечаете» выделено **парным знаком**? Это как бы пауза, общая остановка в речи. А если убрать левую запятую, то слово сместится туда же, влево, будет относиться к уже сказанному. Нет вопросительного знака? Значит, не вопрос это, а уверенность в том, что вы слушаете, замечаете и понимаете все.

Да уж, перечитаешь отрывок несколько раз – и будешь какое-то время походить на князя Мышкина и думать, как он.  Может, это и не помешает в какой-то мере, если очень не увлекаться. Как  утверждают психологи и фантасты, привязанность к постоянной форме не считается позитивным качеством нашей цивилизации. :)

Answer (score 0):

«Больше всего интересует часть с выделением слова "замечаете" - почему оно отделено с обеих сторон тире?» — Это *присоединительная связь*.

> Присоединительные члены предложения, которые содержат дополнительные разъяснения или замечания, вводимые в середину либо в конец высказывания, выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми (реже используются тире, точка, многоточие).
>
> http://www.old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

«...в оригинальном тексте стоит именно запятая, хотя я бы при письме употребила все же другой знак препинания». Будете писать своего «Идиота» — употребите свой таинственный другой знак. А автору захотелось именно запятой, — право имеет! :)